# Write data to stdin of an executable file in the shell script

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to build some basic functionality. I'm running simple c code, which reads the data from the stdin file stream and prints. The short snippet of the code is attached below. In my application, I want to start a c code which reads the data through stdin and performs some operation on it, and there will be another process running which sends the data to stdin periodically. Check the pseudo shell script for a better understanding. As I'm a beginner with shell scripting, I don't know how to achieve this task. So, please help me if anyone has done something similar or has clues on how to do it.

```
#!/bin/sh
#I know this won't work because running code and cat command are referring to a different file stream
clear # clearing the screen
echo "running the shell command" #basic eco in the beginning
./a.out & # Run the compiled c code in the background 
while true 
  do
    sleep 2 #2-sec delay
    cat <<< "# check $\n" # send the data to the stdin
  done
exit 0
```

.

```
//regular c file, command: cc filename.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int FnReceiveCharacter(void)
{      
   unsigned char c = 0, d;
   d = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
   fflush(stdin);   
   return c;
}
int main( )
{
  while(1) printf("%c",FnReceiveCharacter( ));
}
```

Comment: usual way is to use a regular linux pipe: `run-process-printing-to-stdin | a.out`

Comment: @Serge a pipe has some caveats, including creating a subshell, see "Input source selection" at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Comment: `cat <<< "anything"` sends contents to the stdin _of `cat`_, but then `cat` sends it back out its stdout (which you never did anything to connect to `a.out`'s stdin), so... what is that meant to accomplish?

Comment: @EdMorton I updated the code, which you can compile now!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I already mentioned that statement before. Ps* I already mentioned that I'm a beginner with shell scripting, and I don't have much experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I can tell all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./a.out < <(
    while true; do
        sleep 2
        echo '# check'
    done
)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
# check
# check
...
```

See the bottom of the "Input source selection" section in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for why I'm using that `< <(...)` redirection from [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) construct instead of a pipe.

Comment: Did you mean to link to [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) instead? I'm not sure I get why #1 would be on-point.

Comment: I updated the code, now I think you can compile that simple code using the GCC compiler (to create the a.out).
Also, I'm getting an error at a.out < <(

Comment: @CharlesDuffy #1 at the bottom of the "Input source selection" section has a small paragraph and example about this and references #24 from it so I figured I'd start there.

Comment: @AatifShaikh if you don't tell us what the error message or unexpected behavior is then we can't help you debug it.

Comment: the error is tst.sh: 4: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: @AatifShaikh, make sure you're running this with `bash` **not** `sh`; `sh` is not bash (even when it is: sometimes `/bin/sh` is a hardlink or symlink to `/bin/bash`, but even then it turns off some features when started under the `sh` name), and it isn't guaranteed to support bash-only syntax like process substitution. So `bash yourscript` not `sh yourscript`, `#!/usr/bin/env bash` not `#!/bin/sh`, etc. Thank of it as being like C vs C++; you can't use C++ syntax with a C compiler.

Comment: Thanks everyone, now I'm able to run it and it is working fine.